# Основы работы с окнами [Rust]

Tags: rust

Я пробовал использовать библиотеку libtcod и там есть готовый функционал создания окон.

Я хочу узнать, как самому создавать окно на windows и linux
И делать минимальные вещи.

Желательно без сторонних библиотек, если это вообще возможно.

Comment: без сторонних скорей всего не как.вроде бы не реализует подобные вещи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создавать окно - это задача операционной системы или специальной оконной системы, которая в ней используется. Для разных операционных систем нужно будет использовать разное внешнее API для этих целей. Например, в Windows вам понадобится вызывать WinAPI функции, а в linux - X11 (как вариант). Можете посмотреть как устроен внутри крейт [winit](https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit) и его зависимости, чтобы примерно понять, как можно реализовать работу с окнами в разных ОС.

Вот [небольшой пример для иксов](https://github.com/erlepereira/x11-rs/blob/master/x11-dl/examples/hello-world-dl.rs) из x11-dl (байндинги к функциям X11 для Rust), от которого зависит winit.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не знал про OSapi